# Can dual national Canadian/EU enter US from UK, with passport only?

Tags: passport, dual-citizenship

I have a dual citizenship one Greek and one Canadian. My plan is to travel to the US. Currently, I live in the UK and not in the EU country (i.e. Greece) in which I was raised. My question is, can I enter the US with my Canadian passport or do I need to do anything prior it as I am not coming from Canada and I am a dual national?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should not really matter where you're coming from. If you apply for admission with your Canadian passport, all you have to do is comply with the requirements for Canadian citizens entering the US. So, if Canadians need a ESTA, you'll have to apply for one.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. According to the legislation, Canadians don't need Visa to access US if it's less than 6 months. They can enter with their passport. So I guess arriving in the US with my Canadian passport should be enough then?

Comment: From what I understand, yes, you are correct. Canadian citizens do not require an ESTA or visa to travel as a visitor to the US.

Comment: Right. There is no need to tell them you have dual nationality.  You are simply a Canadian entering the US.  Your Canadian passport is all you need to enter as a tourist; no visa etc. is required.

Comment: @RayButterworth you are correct: there is no need to mention dual nationality.  That is, unless they ask about it.  In the unlikely event that the topic arises, there's no harm in disclosing the Greek nationality, and it's possible that failing to do so would be seen as deception. There's no need to mention it, but there is also no need to hide it.

Comment: @IanDantas Yes indeed thank you, so I should be fine.

Comment: @RayButterworth@phoog Yeap I understood that point makes sense, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to entering the US with your Canadian passport you'll also need to use that passport to check in for your flight to the US.  Otherwise, the airline would require you to have valid ESTA authorization.  By checking in with the Canadian passport you will avoid any confusion.

Comment: I see, thank you, actually in that case I could ran over that enquiry with my airline.